# Android TextView setText

Tags: android, settext

Okay, so I have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8?">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

(Main Activity) below:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
text.setText("Text Replacement!");
```

This doesn't replace the text, and I do have the class, and main methods. onCreate etc.

It seems that the XML file is the only one it will take a value from, if there's no android:text it shows nothing.

I'm basically trying to just change the text via the .setText function, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
text.setText("Text Replacement");
  }
}


Layouts for files: /storage/emulated/0/AppProjects/New/res/layout/main.xml
                   /storage/emulated/0/AppProjects/New/gen/com/mycompany/New/R.java
                   /storage/emulated/0/AppProjects/New/src/com/mycompany/new/MainActivity.java
```

Comment: where do you inflate layout that contains this textview?

Comment: where did u set the setContentView().... show full code plz.

Comment: In the XML layout you have `android:text=""Text"` change that to `android:text="Text"`, give it another shot and tell us.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: Where exactly is your code? On Activity.onCreate() method? Specify please.

Comment: post the java code of your activity ... the error must be there

Answer (score 2):

Move your findViewById after setContentView(), and change your variable names to follow Java convention:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //this line should be called after you inflate your view with setContentView
        //so move it here, instead in MainActivity body
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
        text.setText("Text Replacement");
    }
}
```

Also, there's a typo in your xml layout. Change this line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8?">
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: You've got a typo in your xml layout, although this shouldn't compile in that case. So your app starts and you see the "Text" instead of "Text replacement", yes?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I only ever see whatever I set in XML as android:text

Comment: Ok, I've just run this in AIDE (and Intellij IDEA btw), and it just works. Please post ALL your code: your class, manifest, layout as you have them in your project. Do it in your original post please.

Comment: Done, if that's what you were asking for, all the code shown is the full code. The only thing missing, is the R.java, and the automated MAINACTIVITY.JAVA imports.

Comment: Also, could you show me your XML code, did you modify any of it? If you didn't, then it can only be the R.java.

Comment: Ok, because it's a simple project, I suggest you delete it and start again in AIDE. My xml layout is exactly the same as yours (save for the typo you have). Also, I don't really see any code that you've added in your post. Please format your code when adding.

Answer (score 1):

Move the below to onCreate

```
TextView Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
```

Like

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
 tv.setText("Text Replacement);
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the current inflated layout. So first you need to set the layout to the activity and then initialize views.

Also consider renaming `Text` to something more appropriate and meaningfull.

Edit:

Make sure you have the textview with id Text in `main.xml`. Build and clean your project.

Comment: Done, still have the same issue. I'm using an editor called AIDE, not Eclipse. Not sure if that could be the issue here?

Comment: @user3128007 sure you have a textview with id `Text` in `main.xml`. if so i see no reason it won't work. if not pls post the complete xml with name and the java code complete

Comment: How would I call the .setText without the findViewById? Sorry, I'm new to Android.

Comment: @user3128007 post your complete class code and xml. DO you have any other method other than `onCreate`??

Comment: No, one second, I will get the full .XML file, that's the full MainActivity.java, without the imports.

Comment: @user3128007 i thought another method `findViewById` in your class other than the one use here `TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);`. Bcoz it should work if you have textview in main.xml. I see no reason why it won't work

Comment: There's my whole XML file. I don't have another method, although I have other projects.

Comment: @user3128007 should work no reason why it won't work. i see nothing wrong

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is the IDE I am using, which is AIDE, and that's on my tablet.

Comment: @user3128007 could be i am not sure i have only used Eclipse and android-studio. The code to me looks fine

Comment: Could you test it on Eclipse for me, and see if it works, please?

Comment: @user3128007 i am absolutetly sure it will work. No need to test

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find your views before `setContentView()` method. Move your lines after `setContentView()`:

```
TextView Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
Text.setText("Text Replacement);
```

Also, please follow java naming conventions, as obect names never start with Caps but class names do..

Comment: I've done that, but it still takes the XML value, and ignores the MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

You should innialize your view and set proper properties in andriod after setContentView method is been called.

So this below code should come after setcontent view

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
    text.setText("Text Replacement);
```

Comment: Done, but still nothing.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8?"> remove this line from xml. it shud work. Put comment it wont work.

Comment: I've fixed it now, there was no issue with the code, aside from some typos I made. I wasn't directly compiling into a Android application, and for some reason that was stopping it from updating the full text value from MAINACTIVITY.java, so it went to the XML value. thanks a lot for your response though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two "" before the "Text"

Try deleting one...
Should look like this:

```
android:text="Text"/>
```

Comment: If that was the problem the compiler would told him. So my guess it's not.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo sorry, I've had to copy it from my Nexus, to my PC. It's "" in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Ur variable is declared as **TextView Text**

Instead u should use **text** because in Java Anything starting with capital letter is treated as a class ,it is a bad programming practice ! The variables should be in lowercase([hungerian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation))  !

Comment: I've done that, I renamed it to text, but it's still just getting the XML value, not the MainActivity value

Answer (score 0):

First, consider using "wrap_content" or "match_parent" attributes instead of "200dp" for example.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Text"/>
```

Then, please rename your "Text" variable into "text". Java or Android may be thinking that Text is not your variable but a class:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
text.setText("Text Replacement!");
```